# Itemscontrol sharing grid between controltemplate and itemtemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` which has lots of columns and a static header row.

I'm aware of `HeaderedItemsControl` but I'm not sure it can achieve what I want.

What I currently have is the `ControlTemplate` serving as the container for the header and the `ItemsPresenter`, then the `ItemTemplate` is used to organise the records.

At the moment I've got a duplicate grid in both the content and item templates, and I want to find an elegant solution where I can share the same grid between both templates so I don't have to change two things when editing it around. Mock up of what it look like below, the actual control has many more columns. I've read about `IsSharedSizeScope` and `SharedSizeGroup` but I gather this wouldn't work because it only functions when there are two grids sharing a parent element (they would both need to be inside the ControlTemplate)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Col1" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Col2" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Col3" />
                </Grid>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="ItemCol1" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="ItemCol2" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="ItemCol3" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I've probably done something that is bad practice as well so feel free to give me pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you set the value of ItemsSource completely wrong.

It should look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}">
```

When I take your example and run it all works fine to me.

If you wish to share column sizes then yes you could use the SharedSizeGroup. You will have to set the scope to be the ItemsControl.

You got the wrong definition of SharedSizeGroup. It works no matter where the Grids are placed as long they share same one of their parents. Which is the case for you since ItemsControl is the top most control so it is the parent to every control inside.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, yeah I edited the example when I was putting in the response, the binding is what it is actually like I'll change that. Am I going to be able to remove all but the <grid> tags for one of the grids?